# What is an area parameter in Html.Action class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am studying ASP.NET MVC4. I don't quite understand what the `area` parameter is in the code below.

```
<section id="myWorkingSection">
    @Html.Action("myActionName", "myController", new { area = "Widgets", workingSection = "myWorkingSection" })
</section>
```

`myActionName` takes `workingSection` as parameter but it does not take `area` as parameter. My guess is that since `Widgets` is the name of the folder, is it telling that the controller `myController` is located in the `Widgets` folder?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a route parameter used to specify the area within MVC.

In your case the area is `Widgets`.

[Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)